# Extract a value from each text file obeying a naming convention - how?

Tags: python, file, text, extract

I need to extract the last number in the last line of each text file in a directory. Can someone get me started on this in Python? The data is information formatted as follows:

```
# time 'A' 'B'
  0.000000E+00 10000 0
  1.000000E+05 7742 2263
```

where the '#' column is empty in each file. The filenames obey the following naming convention:

```
for i in `seq 1 100`; for j in `seq 1 101`; for letter in {A..D}; 
filename = $letter${j}_${i}.txt
```

These files contain the resulting data from running simulations in KaSim (Kappa language). I want to take the averages of subsets of the extracted numbers and plot some results.

Matlab can't handle the set of 50,000 files I'm dealing with. I'm relatively new to Python but I have experience in Matlab and R. I want to do the data extraction through Python and the analysis in Matlab or R.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should get you started. As far as the directory has only those files for which you need the last number, the naming convention can be ignored. Because, you can rather look up all of the file in that directory.

```
import glob

last_numbers = []
for filename in glob.glob("/path/to/directory/*"):  # dont forget this ending * (its wild character)
    last_number = file.open(filename).readlines()[-1].split(" ")[-1]
    # in case last line is empty line '\n' and your interest is in last second line then it should be '.readlines()[-2].split(" ")[-1]'
    last_numbers.append(last_number)
```

Comment: Thank you - I will decipher this code and test it out!